# Reposting Question about Schroder-Bernstein

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

Assume there exists a $1$-$1$ function $f:X\to Y$ and another $1$-$1$ function $g:Y\to X$. Follow the steps to show that there exists a $1$-$1$, onto function $h:X\to Y$ and hence $X\sim Y$.

a) The range of $f$ is defined by

$$f(X)=\{y\in Y:y=f(x)\text{ for some }x\in X\}\;.$$

Let $y\in f(X)$. Explain why there exists a unique $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Now define $f^{−1}(y)=x$, and show that $f^{−1}$ is a $1$-$1$ function from $f(X)$ onto $X$. In a similar way, we can also define the $1$-$1$, onto function $g^{−1}:g(Y)\to Y$.

b) Let $x\in X$ be arbitrary. Let the chain $C_x$ be the set consisting of all elements of the form:

$$\ldots,f^{−1}(g^{−1}(x)),g^{−1}(x),x,f(x),g(f(x)),f(g(f(x))),\ldots$$

Explain why the number of elements to the left of $x$ in the above chain may be zero, finite, or infinite.

c) Show that any two chains are either identical or completely disjoint.

d) Note that the terms in the chain above alternate between elements of $X$ and elements of $Y$, i.e.,

$$\ldots f^{−1}(g^{−1}(x))\in X,g^{−1}(x)\in Y,x\in X,f(x)\in Y,g(f(x))\in X,f(g(f(x)))\in Y\ldots\tag{1}$$

Given a chain $C_x$, focus on $C_x\cap Y$, which is just the part of the chain that belongs to $Y$. Define the set $A$ to be the union of all chains $C_x$ satisfying $C_x\cap Y\subseteq f(X)$. Let $B$ be the set of the union of the remaining chains not in $A$. Show that any chain contained in $B$ must be of the form:

$$y,g(y),f(g(y)),g(f(g(y))),\ldots$$

where $y$ is an element of $Y$ that is not in $f(X)$.

---

I need help with part d

Comment: Jason: There’s a tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on writing mathematics for this site.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please rewrite your question such that it only includes the question you want to ask and enough background for people to answer it. This post contains a lot of unnecessary text. Also, please show what you have tried yourself to solve your question.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $C_x$ is in $B$; then there is a $y\in(C_x\cap Y)\setminus f[X]$, and I claim that $y$ is the first element of the chain $C_x$. Since $y\in C_x\cap Y$, either $y=g^{-1}(u)$ for some $u\in X$, or $y=f(u)$ for some $u\in X$. The second is impossible, since $y\notin f[X]$, so $y=g^{-1}(u)$ for some $u\in X$. If there is a term before $y$, that term must be $f^{-1}\big(g^{-1}(u)\big)$, which is in $X$. But then

$$g^{-1}(u)=f\big(f^{-1}\big(g^{-1}(u)\big)\big)\in f[X]\;,$$

which is impossible by the choice of $y$. Thus, $y$ must in fact be the first element of the chain $C_x$. The rest is easy.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I am shaky on the part about y=g−1(u) for some u∈X  , because g:Y->X , so g^-1: g(Y)->Y.

Comment: @Jason: But $g[Y]\subseteq X$, so anything in the domain of $g^{-1}$ is an element of $X$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jason: You’re welcome!